# How to dump list of strings in pandas dataframe keeping target columns unchanged?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have a dataframe where the first column `Text` contains list of strings, and other two columns (`Label1` and `Label2`) contain labels. The dataframe looks like below:

```
|Text                |Label1  |  Label2 |
----------------------------------------- 
| ['text1', 'text2', |  0     |    0 
   'text3']
-----------------------------------------
| ['text4', 'text5', |  1     |    1 
   'text6']
-----------------------------------------
    ....         ..           ..
```

Now, I want to separate these strings from lists so that each of the texts inside lists make its individual row keeping its labels same. For example, My output dataframe should be like below:

```
|  Text              |Label1  |  Label2 |
----------------------------------------- 
|  text1             |  0     |    0    |
-----------------------------------------
|  text2             |  0     |    0    |
-----------------------------------------
|  text3             |  0     |    0    |
-----------------------------------------
|  text4             |  1     |    1    |
-----------------------------------------
|  text5             |  1     |    1    |
-----------------------------------------
|  text6             |  1     |    1    |
-----------------------------------------
    ....         ..           ..
```

I am not sure what would be title of this question. But how can I solve this problem using Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.explode` on the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : [['text1', 'text2', 'text3'], ['text4', 'text5', 'text6']],
                   'Label1' : [0, 1], 'Label2' : [0, 1]})

df_exploded = df.explode('Text') #explode on column 'Text'
```

Result:

```
    Text  Label1  Label2
0  text1       0       0
0  text2       0       0
0  text3       0       0
1  text4       1       1
1  text5       1       1
1  text6       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is `explode`:

```
df.explode('Text')
```